# How to persist Keystore and package name if ejecting expo from react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to eject expo from my react native application and change it to react-native, since the application size is pretty huge on both the platforms. It's 50 MB on android and 147 MB on iOS. However, is there a way from where I can persist my packageName and bundleIdentifiers(If I am creating a new project)

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to change the package name or bundle name when using the `expo eject`' command?

Comment: Yes. Is is possible?